# get ArrayList from Parse Object

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, parse-platform

I have a Parse Object that has a value which contains an ArrayList of User Id's. I'm having trouble figuring out how to retrieve that entire ArrayList (NOT just 1 value from the list) My code looks something like this.. but always comes with errors (Array comes back empty):

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Food");
    query.whereEqualTo("objectId", parseId);
    query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                  ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) 
   parseObject.get("userList");// This is where I don't know what to use to get the Array

}

else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ThisActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle(R.string.error_title)
                        .setMessage("error")
                        .setPositiveButton("ok", null);
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
         }
    });
```

I want to just load the array of user id's (from the object) and use the array elsewhere in this activity. All the other values in the object are String values and load just fine with the .getString.

I know I'm probably way off so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @IdusOrtus it's from the parse.com API.  I think the object returned from `get` will be a JSONArray, not an ArrayList.  You can confirm with a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Try This To Retrieve All Records In Server using findInBackground()
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Food");
query.whereEqualTo("objectId", parseId);
query.findInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
@Override
public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObject, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
    for (int i = 0; i<parseObject.size(); i++){
        ParseObject stObj = parseObject.get(i);
        List<String>list = stObj.getList("userList");
        //Transfer list content to array stockArr
        String[] stockArr = new String[list.size()];
        stockArr = list.toArray(stockArr);
        //list contains userlist - To add to list without transferring content to array use next line of code below
        list.add("Add This To The List");
        //To save updated list use next two lines of code below
        stObj.put("userList", list);
        stObj.saveInBackground();
    }
    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ThisActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.error_title)
                .setMessage("error")
                .setPositiveButton("ok", null);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
    }
});


//Try This To Retrieve ONLY First Record In Server using getFirstInBackground()
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Food");
query.whereEqualTo("objectId", parseId);
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
@Override
public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObject, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
        ParseObject stObj = parseObject.get(0);
        List<String>list = stObj.getList("userList");
        //Transfer list content to array stockArr
        String[] stockArr = new String[list.size()];
        stockArr = list.toArray(stockArr);
    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ThisActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.error_title)
                .setMessage("error")
                .setPositiveButton("ok", null);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace this line:

```
parseObject.get("userList");// This is where I don't know what to use to get the Array
```

to:

```
JSONArray array = parseObject.getJSONArray("userList");
```

And it shall work without any problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you don't have to use `getFirstInBackground` (that retrieve only one element) but you have to use `findInBackground` (to retrieve all the objects).